# Weierstrass approximation theorem proof by Gram-Schmidt orthogonal polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, polynomials

I am familiar with Bernstein proof of Weierstrass Theorem. However, I am curious whether it can be proven by using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of $x^n, n=0,\dots,N$ monomials? As $N\rightarrow\infty$
it is easy to see that $f(x)$ can be fitted exactly on $N+1$ equidistant points, say in $[0,1]$ interval. It becomes problematic to estimate max difference in intervals between these points. I realize that the derivative of $P_N(x)$ is limited by that of $x^N$ but then things become clumsy. It seems so obvious that either has been proven long time ago or demonstrated to be false approach. I am simply curious. Thank you.

Comment: It seems you mention two ideas:  Gram-Schmidt, and interpolation.  Gram-Schmidt is good for $L^2$ approximation, not uniform.  Interpolation suffers from something called "Runge Phenomenon", which says polynomial interpolation can behave badly between the interpolation points.  I am not really clear on what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

The Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization wrto the Lebesgue measure on the interval $[-1,1]$ produces the Legendre polynomials. Like the trigonometric expansion, the Fourier expansion of a continuous function in  Legendre polynomials in general does not converge uniformly, but it does if $f$ is slightly more regular:  check e.g [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-278/S0025-5718-2011-02549-4/S0025-5718-2011-02549-4.pdf) and references therein.